# Kronig-Penney Model $P$ vs $E$ graph

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, operators, solid-state-physics, harmonic-oscillator

While studying the [Kronig-Penney model](https://lampx.tugraz.at/%7Ehadley/ss1/KronigPenney/KronigPenney.php) the author introduced a quantity

$$P=\frac{mVba}{h^2}$$

Where $b$ and $a$ are periodic lengths and $V$ is the potential barrier.

Then he explain the extreme value cases for $P\rightarrow\infty$ and $P\rightarrow 0$
But I did not get how he ended up on the following graph between $P$ and $E$ for allowed and forbidden energy.

[source:Solid State Physics R.K. Puri and V.K. Babbar]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The condition for a given value of the energy to exist looks like
$$\cos(ka) = \cos(\alpha a)+P\frac{\sin(\alpha a)}{\alpha a}$$
where $\alpha a \propto \sqrt{E}$. Solutions to this equation exist provided that the right-hand side lies in the interval $[-1,1]$, so the "allowed energies" correspond to the values of $\alpha a$ which satisfy this condition.

If $P=0$, then $\cos(\alpha a)\in[-1,1]$ for *all* values of the energy and so all energies are allowed. For general values of $P$, there is no simple analytic expression for the allowed energies, but they are plotted in the figure you display.